# .net core 2.2, Reading setting from user secrets for serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-2.2

I have set up my solution and serilog reads the values from appsettings.json

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application, IHostingEnvironment environment, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     Logger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
     loggerFactory.AddSerilog(log);
```

And the appsettings looks like this:

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Slack", "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }

    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Slack",
        "Args": {
          "WebHookUrl": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/yyy/zzz",
          "CustomChannel": "#channel"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "InstrumentationKey": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

So everything is fine til here, but I don't want to store secrets like webhook and InstrumentationKey in my repository. I want to read them from a safe place like user-secrets on development environment and Key-vault on prouction. How do I change it to replace the values from usersecrets?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows

Is there anyways the config get overriten automatically?

If not, I know I can read my configuration from secrets let's say like

```
  webHookUrl = Configuration["Serilog:WriteTo:Slack:WebHookUrl"];
```

But then how do I apply it on the loggerConfig? I mean, the writeTo part is dynamic from the settings, should I then add it in code instead? :\

### Update

Since many people have asked, in my program.cs I have:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

And based on the Microsoft documentation, everything should work because I have `CreateDefaultBuilder` and I am running .net core 2.2.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows#access-a-secret

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 or later, **the user secrets configuration source is automatically added in development mode when the project calls CreateDefaultBuilder** to initialize a new instance of the host with preconfigured defaults. CreateDefaultBuilder calls AddUserSecrets when the EnvironmentName is Development.

When CreateDefaultBuilder isn't called, add the user secrets configuration source explicitly by calling AddUserSecrets in the Startup constructor. Call AddUserSecrets only when the app runs in the Development environment

Comment: The thing about .Net Core configuration is that it doesn't matter where a setting comes from, as long as one of the providers has ingested a setting it will be available to configuration in general. You can put the serilog settings in any provider like the keyvault provider, environment variables, etc. If you are in an Azure App Service I suggest the service's Application Settings.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks for the reply. I have copied the same exact settings in my secrets and removed it from my appsettings but now I am not receiving any logs. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you setting up the configuration builder? Are you using `builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();`?

Comment: @ESG no, because I am on .net core 2.2 so I should be fine with   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args). Shouldn't I?

Comment: @AshkanSirous No, secrets are only loaded on demand (and typically only in dev envionrments)

Comment: Did you `AddSerilog()` after adding UserSecrets? Is your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to "development"?

Comment: @ESG why? it says in the documentation that I should only add it if I am not using CreateDefaultBuilder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows#access-a-secret In ASP.NET Core 2.0 or later, the user secrets configuration source is automatically added in development mode when the project calls CreateDefaultBuilder to initialize a new instance of the host with preconfigured defaults. CreateDefaultBuilder calls AddUserSecrets when the EnvironmentName is Development

Comment: @Crowcoder please take a look at my update. I\ve checked the environment by checking environment.IsDevelopment() and yes it is development :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm currently using for my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web applications. It supports `appsettings.json` (for all environments) and Visual Studio's User Secrets (`secrets.json`) without having to write any sensible info (such as the user secret's unique ID) the code.

**Program.cs** file's `Main()` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",
            optional: false,
            reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", 
            optional: true,
            reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddUserSecrets<Startup>(optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.MariaDB(
            restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information,
            connectionString: configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
            tableName: "Logs",
            autoCreateTable: false,
            useBulkInsert: false,
            options: new MariaDBSinkOptions() 
            { 
                LogRecordsExpiration = new TimeSpan(90, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
            })
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting the HostBuilder...");
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "The HostBuilder terminated unexpectedly");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

**Program.cs** file's `CreateWebHostBuilder()` method:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
            {
                // Set properties and call methods on options
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .UseSerilog();
```

If you need additional info, take a look at [this post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-database-logging-ilogger-sql-server-mysql-mariadb-serilog/) on my blog.

Comment: Does the `AddUserSecrets` line present any problems when the code running in a non-development environment?

Comment: No problems, as long as `optional` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have copied the same exact settings in my secrets and removed it from my appsettings but now I am not receiving any logs. Am I missing something?

If you move your serilog configurations from `appsettings.json` to `secrets.json`, you need to modify the `ReadFrom.Configuration()` in `Configure` to read from secrets.json.

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddJsonFile("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\UserSecrets\\aspnet-SerilogCore\\secrets.json")
          .Build();//Replace above with path of your secrets.json

Logger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
loggerFactory.AddSerilog(log);
```

Comment: Instead of adding the `secrets.json` full path in clear text (which is not that great) you can use the `.AddUserSecrets()` method in the following way: `.AddUserSecrets(<Startup>(optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)`. I've added a dedicated answer to better explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that @Crowcoder is correct in his 1st comment to the OP. Therefore, what you need to do is "dupliclate" the structure and part of the configuration from your appsettings.json into the secrets.json file in your home directory

So in your case, you would do something like this:

```
    "Serilog": {

    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Slack",
        "Args": {
          "WebHookUrl": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/yyy/zzz"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "InstrumentationKey": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

So that only the secret information is present.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specifically for "***How do I user User Secrets with Serilog?***".

The User Secrets json must mirror the json structure in your `Serilog` section. If you have defined 2 Serilog sinks, but only have one user secret, then the User Secrets json still needs to include both sinks (sort of - see examples below).

Why? The User Secrects must match the ordinal indexes of the "WriteTo" array in your Serilog configuration. See the following examples based on OP's Serilog json.

**Note**: *The inclusion of the `WriteTo[idx].Name` value is not needed, but included so it's easier to read the user secrets. Remeber, the User Secrets does not use the name of the sink, but matches the index-based definition in the Serilog `WriteTo` array; you do not need to include the `WriteTo[idx].Name` key/value in User Secrets. But, if you do, make sure the name exactly matches the actual sink's name, otherwise it will overwrite the config value.*

### User Secrets JSON examples

#### Both sinks/WriteTo have User Secrets

```json
{
  "SomeOtherConfig": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Slack",
        "Args": {
          "WebHookUrl": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/my/secret/url",
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "InstrumentationKey": "my-secret-instrumentation-key"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Only the first sinks/WriteTo has User Secrets

Since the User Secrets will match the index of the `WriteTo` array, only the first sink w/ the user secret needs to be included.

```json
{
  "SomeOtherConfig": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Slack",
        "Args": {
          "WebHookUrl": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/my/secret/url",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Only the last sinks/WriteTo has User Secrets

Since the User Secrets will match the index of the `WriteTo` array, the first sink place-holder must be included w/ the user secret, and the second sync with the user secret needs to be included.

```json
{
  "SomeOtherConfig": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Slack",
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "InstrumentationKey": "my-secret-instrumentation-key"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```